# Value for AUTH_USER_MODEL in Django settings file

Tags: python, django

In Django whenever we want to use a model with name `model_name` in a file then we have to import that model as

`from app_name.models import model_name`

And when we have to use a custom user model in the project as **User model**, we have to specify a reference to that model in the **settings.py** file as

`AUTH_USER_MODEL = app_name.model_name`

So my question is why we have to specify the value for **AUTH_USER_MODEL** in the **settings.py** file as

`app_name.model_name`

and not as

`app_name.models.model_name`

why we are not using mentioning `models.py` file in value for the **AUTH_USER_MODEL** in the **settings.py** file

Comment: Because it is a model, hence `.model` would be *redundant*.

Answer (score 0):

At startup django import `models` module for each application and register all `Model` subclasses.

[`django/apps/registry.py`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/_modules/django/apps/registry/):

```py
        # Mapping of app labels => model names => model classes. Every time a
        # model is imported, ModelBase.__new__ calls apps.register_model which
        # creates an entry in all_models. All imported models are registered,
        # regardless of whether they're defined in an installed application
        # and whether the registry has been populated. Since it isn't possible
        # to reimport a module safely (it could reexecute initialization code)
        # all_models is never overridden or reset.
        self.all_models = defaultdict(dict)
```

Models are not referenced by there python module but by their `app_label` and `model_name` (lowercase).
Lookup for a model is performed by `app_label` and `model_name`.

User model doesn't except:

[`django/contrib/auth/__init__.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py#L155):

```
def get_user_model():
    """
    Return the User model that is active in this project.
    """
    try:
        return django_apps.get_model(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, require_ready=False)
    ...
```

In lots cases, `app_label` is also the name of the module for that application, which can be confusing.